# How to Replace Content in Header of Word Document using Python-docx?

Tags: python, ms-word, header, python-docx

I am working on a project where I need to dynamically replace certain placeholders in the header of a Word document using Python. [The header content looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVJKK.png).

I have a JSON file with the new values:

```
{
    "<<company_name>>": "Some Ltd",
    "<<company_number>>": "123123"
}
```

I need to replace the existing content in the header with these new values. I've tried various methods, but I can't seem to figure out how to replace the placeholders with values from the JSON file. Can someone provide a step-by-step guide or code snippet to achieve this using the python-docx library?

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
def replace_placeholders(doc, data):
    for section in doc.sections:
        # Replace placeholders in the header
        for paragraph in section.header.paragraphs:
            for run in paragraph.runs:
                for key, value in data.items():
                    run.text = run.text.replace(key, str(value))
```

Additional: [This is the Word doc I work with. It is just sample.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4fLp.png)

I need to replace the values in the header with new values.

By the way, here is the code that I wrote to replace words in the body of the Word doc:

```
from docx import Document
import json

def replace_placeholders(doc, data):
    for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
        for run in paragraph.runs:
            for key, value in data.items():
                run.text = run.text.replace(key, str(value))

# Load Word document
doc_path = "template2 (1).docx"
doc = Document(doc_path)


json_file_path = "new.json"
with open(json_file_path, 'r') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

# Replace placeholders in the document
replace_placeholders(doc, data)

# Save the modified document
modified_doc_path = "modified_document.docx"
doc.save(modified_doc_path)

print(f"Document '{doc_path}' has been updated and saved to '{modified_doc_path}'.")
```

Comment: step 1: read JSON file

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: Yes, I did this.

Comment: Oh OK, will do the print debugging!

Comment: Actually, I tried another thing, just to see if the content will be replaced at all.

Comment: frankly, for this problem we would need `minimal working code` with example Word file - so we could test this problem on your file.

Comment: Yes, I am trying with minimal working code and example Word doc.

Comment: maybe show this code and Word doc - so we could also test it.

Comment: I edited the post and added screenshot of the Word doc I work with, I am not sure if I can upload the Word doc directly here.

Comment: Only the replacement in the header is not working! In the body of the doc, the replacement is working.

Comment: maybe it looks like your `placeholder` but it use similar chars with different `UTF-8` codes. Did you use `print()` to check what you really have in variables? You may also try to check strings in header char-by-char using `ord(char)` to see `UTF-8` codes